# Get regular expression for Regex hero to select one string of changing text once scanned with Drivve OCR

Tags: regex, string, expression, ocr

Deliver To.
Random Company Ltd
Car Road
Stoke
St5 4tt

I need to get regex hero to select the second line (Random Company Ltd) as I will eventually integrate it with Drivve for scanning delivery notes, This means that the second line will always be different once scanned with OCR. Does anyone know what regular expression I would need to select just the second line even though the text will be different on every document. I have tried so many regular expressions with no luck and struggling to understand it.
Im using CRLF format. I had \A.* but that only selects the first line whereas I need the second.

Comment: Could you share with us what you tried so far? Also, what language do you use?

Comment: Why a regex? Why not just get the 2nd line using app code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
/(?<=\r\n)[^\r\n]*/
```

Explanation:

- `(?<=\r\n)` - positive lookbehind for CRLF, e.g what follows is the second line
- `[^\r\n]*` - match everything until end of line

Comment: No, `[^\r\n]*` means everything *not* matching CRLF, e.g. it matches only the second line if followed after `(?<=\r\n)`